# Simpy: An RMFS simulation with Simpy

Tags: simulation, simpy

i have a project and i am trying to simulate a RMFS warehouse with simpy. i would really appreciate it anyone can help me as i'm new to simpy and stuck and i dont know how to model it.  i tried different codes but none of them work as they should. here is my assumptions:
1- the Warehouse is a grid and each cell contain many quantity of 1 type of item(item 1,2,3,...).something like the attached photo. it have a unique address
2- orders come in a predefined time (like with uniform distribution of 2 minutes)
3- the orders then is assigned to a robot (we have 10 robots) to go and retrieve the order. it will take 3 minutes
4- then the robot deliver the order to a workstation for next step (like pick the order from robot and package it). it will take 2 minutes.
5- then the robot go and put the order back and wait for next order.

[image]

Comment: how far have you gotten?  I assume each cell can only be seized by one robot (this would be the tricky part)? Got any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gave it a shot, the process I modeled is

basic process:

- order arrives,
- order gets a robot (wait in a queue if all robots are    in use),
- order gets cell (wait if cell has been seized by another    order),
- pick from cell,
- put cell back,
- release robot

so rather then have the cells be a pool of resources (that would need a matching function to get the desired cell), each cell has its own resource pool of capacity of 1.  I use this to queue requests for the cell and all the cells are in a dict for easy access

in hind sight, I think I could get better throughput if I had the order seize the cell before seizing the robot.

```
"""
modes a robot warehouse where robots get pulls a cell
and brings it to a picker who picks stuff from the cell,
then returns the cell back to the warehouse

basic process:
order arrives
order gets a robot (wait in a queue if all robots are in use)
order gets cell (wait if cell has been seized by another order)
pick from cell
put cell back
release robot

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Order():
    """
    Order to be fulfilled

    has unique id for tracking
    and the cell id to pull
    """

    # class var used to gen unique ids
    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self, cell):
        """
        initalizes a order with a unique id and a cell to pull
        """

        # set unique id
        self.id = Order.next_id
        Order.next_id += 1

        # set cell to pull
        self.cell = cell

class Cell():
    """
    Cell that robots retrieve so pickers can pick
    
    A cell can only be seized by one robot at a time
    so each cell has its own request queue implemented 
    with a simple resouce.  Could have put all the cells in 
    one matching store, but I think this is more effecient
    as the matching can be slow with big queues
    """
    
    def __init__(self, env, id):
        """
        Initializes a cell with a id, and a request/resouce queue
        """

        self.id = id
        self.env = env

        # used to queue requests for the cell
        self.resQueue = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

        # request that currently holds the cell's resource
        self.request = None

    def seize(self):
        """
        gets in queue and waits to seize cell
        """

        request = self.resQueue.request()  # Generate a request event
        yield request

        # save the request that has the cell so can release latter
        self.request = request

        return self

    def release(self):
        """
        releases the cell so other robots can seize it
        """

        yield self.resQueue.release(self.request)
        self.request = None

def gen_orders(env, cellMap, robots):
    """
    Generates orders at a random distrubution
    and kicks off the fill order process for the order
    """

    while True:
        # time between arrivals
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(0,2))

        # create order and assign cell
        cell = random.randint(1,len(cellMap))
        order = Order(cell)
        print(env.now, f'Order {order.id} has been created')

        # start process to fulfill the order
        # do not use yield here, just drop and go to next order
        env.process(fill_order(order,cellMap, robots))

def fill_order(order, cellMap, robots):
    """
    the order filling process

    this process gets created for each order
    """

    # get a robot
    print(env.now, f'order {order.id} waits for robot')
    with robots.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has a robot')

        # get the cell
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} waits for cell {order.cell}')
        cell = cellMap[order.cell]
        yield env.process(cell.seize())
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has seized cell {order.cell}')
       
       # pull the cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has pulled cell {order.cell}')

        # pick
        yield env.timeout(2)
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has picked')

        # return cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        env.process(cell.release())
        print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has return cell {order.cell}')

    # release robot
    print(env.now, f'order {order.id} has released a robot')


# start building the sim
env = simpy.Environment()

# made only 10 cells so orders are more likely to compete for a cell
cellMap = {id:Cell(env,id) for id in range(1,10)}

robots = simpy.Resource(env,capacity=10)

# start generating orders, which also kicks off the processing for each order
env.process(gen_orders(env, cellMap, robots))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: your assumption is correct. your code is great. the issues are 1) we need a queue in front of the picker (we can treat it as a resource with 1 capacity) and the main part 2) is the layout of the cells. they have a grid layout (like the photo I attached to the first post) and they have 2 kinds of cell (internal cells and external cells). external cells can be pulled by 1 robots but for internal cells I'm thinking to introduce another resource (like a lift) to pick up the obstacle cell so the robot can pull the order cell. please let me know what you think and how can I do that. thanks

Comment: i am working to add the things I mentioned to the code and I will post it here once it finished. please let me know if you could solve it in meanwhile. really appreciate your help

Comment: please check https://citi-ntust.squarespace.com/en/research/kiva also. im trying to simulate this RMFS but with high density

Comment: The picker should not be too hard.  I agree  the picker can be model with aa a resource with a capacity of 1.  This also allows you to model 2 pickers by upping the capacity to 2.  Just make a picker process that you yield to in the fill_order process where the picker timeout is

Comment: I did not read the article, but, I think what would happen is the robot would move the outer cell to a "hold" spot, assuming the cell has not been pulled by another robot, and then the robot would pull the target cell.  When the robot returns the cell, it would have to check if the outer cell is in the hold spot (could have been pulled by another bot) if it is in the hold spot, return to the cell's home spot.  This would mean he cell class would need a inner cell flag, outer cell id, and in hold spot flag.  Obviously there are a lot more little details but this covers the main logic

Comment: may also need a in hold flag

Comment: my idea is to divide the problem into 2 scenarios. 1) if the cell belongs to outer cells which is the same as you did in the code 2) if the cell is in inside grids. in that case, a lift would take out the outer cells and the robot will pull the inner cell. the lift would have to repeat this in returning the cell as well.

Comment: would you be able to help me put these ideas in code ? I'm not sure I can do it.

Comment: can you give it a try?  break it down into sprints.  In the current code I seize the robot, then I seized a cell.  So for sprint 1 change the code to seize the cell before the robot.  When you get that working move to sprint 2 where you add a flag to the cells marking the if the cell is inner or outer.  up the code so if a cell is inner it also seizes a lift from a lift resource pool, and does a lift time out, and then release the lift.  When you get this done you should have a good idea on how to do the rest

Comment: thanks @michael. i will try to make it work based on your comments

Comment: i added some lines. i would appreciate your comments

Answer (score 0):

this is the update for the code considering a 6*9 Warehouse. i also added a lifting mechanism to it. i appreciate your comments on how we can improve and optimize it. and how to add reporting to it.

```
"""
modes a robot warehouse where robots get pulls a cell
and brings it to a picker who picks stuff from the cell,
then returns the cell back to the warehouse

basic process:
order arrives
order gets a robot (wait in a queue if all robots are in use)
order gets cell (wait if cell has been seized by another order)
pick from cell
put cell back
release robot

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random
random.seed(0)


NUM_ROBOTS = 10
NUM_PICKERS = 1
NUM_GANTRY = 2
EXT_CELLS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13,18,19,24,25,30,31,36,37,42,43,48,49,50,51,52,53,54]
INT_CELLS = [8,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,32,33,34,35,38,39,40,41,44,45,46,47]


class Order():
    """
    Order to be fulfilled

    has unique id for tracking
    and the cell id to pull
    """

    # class var used to gen unique ids
    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self, cell):
        """
        initalizes a order with a unique id and a cell to pull
        """

        # set unique id
        self.id = Order.next_id
        Order.next_id += 1

        # set cell to pull
        self.cell = cell


class Cell():
    """
    Cell that robots retrieve so pickers can pick

    A cell can only be seized by one robot at a time
    so each cell has its own request queue implemented
    with a simple resource.
    """

    def __init__(self, env, id):
        """
        Initializes a cell with a id, and a request/resource queue
        """

        self.id = id
        self.env = env

        # used to queue requests for the cell
        self.resQueue = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

        # request that currently holds the cell's resource
        self.request = None

    def seize(self):
        """
        gets in queue and waits to seize cell
        """

        request = self.resQueue.request()  # Generate a request event
        yield request

        # save the request that has the cell so can release latter
        self.request = request

        return self

    def release(self):
        """
        releases the cell so other robots can seize it
        """

        yield self.resQueue.release(self.request)
        self.request = None


def gen_orders(env, cellMap, robots):
    """
    Generates orders at a random distribution
    and kicks off the fill order process for the order
    """

    while True:
        # time between arrivals
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1.0/1.5))

        # create order and assign cell
        cell = random.randint(1, len(cellMap))
        order = Order(cell)
        print('{:.2f} Order {}  received for item in cell #{}'.format(env.now, order.id,order.cell))

        # start process to fulfill the order
        # do not use yield here, just drop and go to next order
        if cell in EXT_CELLS:
            env.process(fill_order(order, cellMap, robots, pickers))
        else:
            env.process(fill_order_internal(order, cellMap, robots, pickers,gantry))




def fill_order(order, cellMap, robots, pickers):
    """
    the order filling process

    this process gets created for each order
    """
    #indicate cell status
    print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} cell {order.cell} is an external cell')

    # get a robot
    print('{:.2f} order {} waits for robot'.format(env.now,order.id))
    with robots.request() as req:
        yield req
        print('{:.2f} order {} assigned to robot# {}'.format(env.now, order.id, robots.count))

        # get the cell
        print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} waits for cell {order.cell}')
        cell = cellMap[order.cell]
        yield env.process(cell.seize())
        print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} has seized cell {order.cell}')

        # pull the cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} has pulled cell {order.cell} by robot#{robots.count}')

        # pick
        with pickers.request() as picker_req:
            yield picker_req
            yield env.timeout(random.triangular(0.5,1.2,1.8))
            print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} has picked')

        # return cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        env.process(cell.release())
        print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} has return cell {order.cell} by robot# {robots.count}')

    # release robot
    print('{:.2f} order {} has released a robot'.format(env.now,order.id))


def fill_order_internal(order, cellMap, robots, pickers,gantry):
    """
    the order filling process for internal cells

    this process gets created for each order
    """
    #indicate cell status
    print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} cell {order.cell} is an internal cell')
    # get a robot
    print('{:.2f} order {} waits for robot and gantry'.format(env.now,order.id))
    with robots.request() as req:
        yield req
        print('{:.2f} order {} assigned to robot# {}'.format(env.now, order.id, robots.count))


        # get the cell
        print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} waits for cell {order.cell}')
        cell = cellMap[order.cell]
        yield env.process(cell.seize())
        print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} has seized cell {order.cell}')

        # get the gantry
        with gantry.request() as req_gantry:
            yield req_gantry
            print('{:.2f} order {} assigned to gantry# {}'.format(env.now, order.id, gantry.count))

        #lift obstacle cells
            yield env.timeout(2)
            print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} has lifted obstacles of cell {order.cell} by gantry{gantry.count}')

        # pull the cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} has pulled cell {order.cell} by robot#{robots.count}')

        # pick
        with pickers.request() as picker_req:
            yield picker_req
            yield env.timeout(random.triangular(0.5,1.2,1.8))
            print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} has picked')

        # get the gantry
        with gantry.request() as req_gantry:
            yield req_gantry
            print('at {:.2f} order {} assigned to gantry# {}'.format(env.now, order.id, gantry.count))

        # lift obstacle cells for return
            yield env.timeout(2)
            print(format(env.now, '.2f'), f'order {order.id} has lifted obstacles of cell {order.cell} by gantry{gantry.count}')

        # return cell
        yield env.timeout(3)
        env.process(cell.release())
        print(format(env.now,'.2f'), f'order {order.id} has return cell {order.cell} by robot# {robots.count}')

    # release robot
    print('at {:.2f} order {} has released a robot'.format(env.now,order.id))

# start building the sim
env = simpy.Environment()

# 54 cells for a 6*9 Warehouse
cellMap = {id: Cell(env, id) for id in range(1, 55)}
#print(cellMap)
robots = simpy.Resource(env, capacity= NUM_ROBOTS)
pickers = simpy.Resource(env, capacity= NUM_PICKERS)
gantry = simpy.Resource(env, capacity= NUM_GANTRY)

# start generating orders, which also kicks off the processing for each order

env.process(gen_orders(env, cellMap, robots))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: The only thing I would have done is to add  a is_internal Cell property, similar to the id property.  With this property you can box the the get the gantry section of fill_order_internal with a if statement (if cell.is_internal:), this way the code will work with both types of Cell so you will only need one function

Comment: As you may have noted reporting is not built in to simpy, but you have all of python to compensate for this.


Your Options are:


1) log you data to a file and process it in another app<p>
2) collect the data in global lists, and dataframes and display it at the end of the simulation in something like matplotlib<p>
3) make the sim into a multi thread app that updates a display on one thread, and runs the sim on the other.(a bit more complicated, but more entertaining for long running sims)

Comment: thanks, @Michael. your comments are great. I really appreciate them.

Comment: Thanks, any chance you could select my answer as correct, or up note some of my comments?